# How to check whether a product already exists or not in a category?

Tags: product, category

In **Manage Products**, before saving the product, I want to check whether the product already exists or not under the category.
For example, I would like to check whether the Product ID 1 already exists or not under category id 1.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you not just look at the assigned categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the category ids from the db like this:
Let's say `$_product` is the current product.

```
$categoryIds = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getCategoryIds($_product);
```

If you do this before saving the product you will get the category ids that are currently stored in the db even if you changed them on the product instance.
I assume you want to perform some actions when the product is saved.
For this create an observer on the event `catalog_product_save_before` that looks like this:

```
public function productSaveBefore($observer) {
     $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
     $oldCategoryIds = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getCategoryIds($product);
     //do your magic here with $oldCategoryIds
}
```

Comment: Hi, Marius, thank you so much! I will try your code and I will get back to you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, Marius, it works. Thank you so much! Now, I am going to accept your answer. Once again, thanks!